# Listener to monitor Android Application

Tags: android, listener, android-broadcast

I need a listener or service , for listening the user activity... Prime objective is that when a user opens and close an application it need to monitor...

Regards

Zacharia

Thanks

Comment: Is it your application or you want to monitor some other application?

Comment: Want to monitor all apps. only one app at a time ...

Comment: I am not sure why you want to do this as it is not recommended but you can check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17629053/how-do-android-monitor-usage-applications-work

Comment: @iago thanks for the link.. is it possible to monitor the intents which comes under a category