# Java android track usage time installed app

Tags: java, android, time, usage-statistics

I need to track usage time of all installed apps, with java, in android OS.
For example, this app is very very similar: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.agrvaibhav.AppUsageTracking

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 3):

First of all you can use the **android.app.ActivityManager** to retrieve phone statue and running processes. An excellent example of doing this could be found here,

[Java Code Examples for android.app.ActivityManager](http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=android.app.ActivityManager)

You can also monitor the foreground activity to determine the Running tasks. Example here,

[how do android monitor usage applications work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17629053/how-do-android-monitor-usage-applications-work)

Lastly you can create your own service to detect each running process and their usage. A complete example of this procedure could be found here,

[App to monitor other apps on android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20416610/app-to-monitor-other-apps-on-android)