# Is there a way to find the total use time of my application

Tags: java, android

Is there library in Android that can provide me  the total spend time of a user in my application without using my own time count?

I believe that Android OS is counting all application use time the same way as they count battery use ,network, etc..
If my assumptions are right, What I need is this system count for my application use time.

Comment: Using this you can: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49174503/6021469

Comment: whole code here: https://github.com/zhaobao/AppsMonitor

Answer (score 0):

You can use Fabric (https://fabric.io/) there's some a lot useful tools that you can use, it also can track Daily Active User, Crash Reporting, etc.

They also provide us easy integration step, just take few minutes to integrate our system with Fabric.

Answer (score -1):

The general approach to this is to:

1. Get the time at the start of your benchmark, say at the start of main().
2. Run your code.
3. Get the time at the end of your benchmark, say at the end of main().
4. Subtract the start time from the end time and convert into appropriate units.

A simpler way is this.

```
long startTime = System.nanoTime();
.....your program....
long endTime   = System.nanoTime();
long totalTime = endTime - startTime;
System.out.println(totalTime);
```

Comment: Let me know if this helps, if yes then please accept the answer

Comment: Thanks for your fast reply, but what  I meant was how can I find the time use of  my application from android OS system without using my own count code?

In other words , is there a library that can provide my application time use?

Comment: I am not sure about that, but this is the new methodology as it uses nanotime