# How to get screen time report in android

Tags: android

How can I get a report in my Android  app with the information time? Is there an API or does anyone know how to access the information?
[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to Get the Time spent on an application in Android Programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32825854/how-to-get-the-time-spent-on-an-application-in-android-programmatically)