# App Usage Time of My App in Android Studio

Tags: android, usage-statistics

I want to get the Time that the user spends on my App and display it to the user (similar to Instagram).
I want to know it for my app only, and not all apps on the users device.

How can I do this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to Get the Time spent on an application in Android Programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32825854/how-to-get-the-time-spent-on-an-application-in-android-programmatically)

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest is to create a timer that is bound to the application lifecycle.
From there, consider the best way to consume less battery